# OData $filter substringof applied to a list of strings

Tags: linq, filter, odata, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Web API Controller that exposes an `IQueryable(Of String)` - which is a list of descriptions. These fields can be in the order of tens of thousands, thus I use `$top` and `$skip` to only get a chunk of it - that works fine.

Now I am trying to filter these results, through the OData `substringof('mydesc',Property)` filter. As you can see, it requires for me to pass in a **Property** name on which to filter. However, since I'm returning a list of strings, I don't actually have any properties to filter on.

This causes the server to return errors like 
`No property or field 'tostring' exists in type 'String'` - when called with `$filter=substringof('asd',tostring)`.

If I change the call to  `$filter=substringof('asd','')`, no errors are thrown, but no results either.

My question is, can I somehow format the `$filter` operator to find substrings within my list of strings, without looking for a property/field, or am I going to have to declare a class with a single property, just to enable filtering?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things have changed since the last time I answered this. OData V3 has support for querying collection of primitives using '$it'. Asp.net Web API supports this syntax as well. For example, in your controller you can return `IQueryable<string>` and send a request like

$filter=substring('mydesc', $it) or

$filter=length($it) ge 5

etc. You can also expose collections of other primitives like IQueryable etc.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately declaring a class with a single property seems to be the only solution that I can think of. `OData $filter` doesn't have any support for something like the `this` parameter in `C#`

Answer (score 0):

another less obvious approach is to expose a computed concatenated value representing the list, substringof could then be used to query the list as a single property value