# How can I query on a match in a list of strings in Breeze?

Tags: c#, javascript, linq, entity-framework, breeze

I have this action in a WebAPI2, EF6 project.

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<ProductListItem> ProductListItems()
{
    // Db.Products is a DbSet<Product>
    return Db.Products.ProductListItemProjection();
}
```

This is a `ProductListItem`  It's not an actual entity - just a projection of one (`Product`):

```
public class ProductListItem : Product
{
    public IEnumerable<string> TagNames { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the `ProductListItemProjection` extension method:

```
public static IQueryable<ProductListItem> ProductListItemProjection(this IQueryable<Product> products)
{
    // Product.Tags is a list of ProductTags.  A ProductTag has a TagType, which in the database is an int,
    // but is backed by an enum (ProductTagTypes) in the .NET model.  The purpose of this expression is to convert
    // the Product.Tags list to a list of strings - display names depending on the TagType of the ProductTag.
    Expression<Func<Product, IEnumerable<string>>> tagNames =
        (Product p) => p.Tags
            .Select(t =>
                t.TagType == ProductTagTypes.Expensive ? "Expensive" :
                t.TagType == ProductTagTypes.Red ? "Red" :
                t.TagType == ProductTagTypes.Liquid ? "Liquid" : "");

    return products
        .AsExpandable() // From LINQKit...
        .Select(p =>
            new ProductListItem
            {
                // Set various properties inherited from Product
                TagNames = tagNames.Invoke(p) // Using LINQKit...
            });
}
```

Is it possible to construct a query in Breeze that queries all of the ProductListItems that have an element matching some given text in `ProductTags`?  I'm not sure how to use the `any` operator with a list of strings, but I tried this:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("ProductListItems")
    .where("tagNames", "any", "" /* Not sure what to put here... just using empty string (also tried 'valueOf') */, "contains", "Expen");
```

But I get a JS error in the breeze library (during query construction, before execution):

```
Error: propertyOrExpr cannot be null except when using the 'IsTypeOf' operator
```

I **can** construct a LINQ to Entities query that works as expected:

```
// Returns ProductListItems that have a tag containing the string "Expen" (i.e., "Expensive")
Db.Users.Query().ProductListItemProjection()
    .Where(u => u.TagNames.Any(r => r.Contains("Expen")));
```

But how can I do this in Breeze? Or is this unsupported? It [appears](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14514017/546561) to be supported in OData v3, but maybe Breeze doesn't support it yet...

**Update**

I might actually have a more general problem.  I tried changing `ProductListItem.TagNames` to be a list of objects with a `Name` property, rather than just a list of strings.  Then I tried:

```
var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("ProductListItems")
    .where("tagNames", "any", "name", "contains", "Expen");
```

And that gets past the query creation, but it fails in `executeQuery` before any request is made to the server :

```
TypeError {query: j, stack: (...), message: "Cannot read property 'isAnonymous' of undefined"}
```

Comment: Consider passing your parameters to the server using `withParameters()` and performing your advanced Linq query there.  The alternative is iterating through each and using indexOf on the client side which, depending on your data size, could use a lot of the resources of the machine.

Comment: @PWKad, I did think about that... There are other columns being filtered though (all need to be OR'ed together with this one), so I'd need to get the OData options (which would include all the other filters OR'ed together), pass those to one query, then do another query that just filters for tags, and union the results of the two queries.  Throw paging and sorting in there (which I'm also doing), and it gets too crazy.